# MySQL: Replicate data within 2 same schemas on 1 mysql server

Tags: mysql, replication

This might sound a bit crazy, please let me explain the reasoning behind this:

- we plan to use a real master-slave replication for production
- we want to use something small'n easy for local development

We mostly have Java/PHP devs who should be *able to inspect state changes* of master/slave databases. The easiest (infrastructure-wise) way seems to be just have a **one MySQL server with 2 same schemas** (so master/slave is not server/server, but schema/schema instead).

Is this easily achievable with MySQL or do we have to install 2 MySQL servers even for local testing?

Comment: you could introduce a trigger on information_schema.processlist to capture all insert/update/delete and generate quires, use those queries according to your requirement. You may also need a script to cater specific requirement. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup a script to read the binary log, convert it to SQL (with the utility [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html)) and change the schema on-the-fly before applying the changes. You could also setup triggers on every table to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` every row on the copy schema. But that is a lot of work to do it right.

[Running 2 instances of MySQL on the same machine is very easy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-servers.html), and may be closer the the production deployment. Tools like [MySQL sandbox](http://search.cpan.org/~gmax/MySQL-Sandbox-3.0.48/lib/MySQL/Sandbox/Recipes.pm#Installing_MySQL::Sandbox) makes running "n" different instances of MySQL even easier, taking just a command to setup an instance or a complex replication topology! You can even simulate replication lag with [MASTER_DELAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html) or [pt-slave-delay](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-slave-delay.html) to see how your application behaves when the state of both schemas is not the same.

Comment: Right, I went for 2 instances after all. Ta.